# git fetch in repo dir 'Permission denied' but working with direct link with user

Tags: git, gerrit

I got an issue with accessing the external repository on gerrit through git.
When I try to *git fetch* in cloned repository directory (clone works well) I get:

```
> git fetch
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I do it directly with repository ssh address and username I get:

```
> git fetch ssh://username@ip:port/repo_name
remote: Counting objects: xxxx, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (xxx/xxx)
etc...
```

So the direct *git fetch* seems to work well.
I've tried to set different usernames with:

```
git config --global user.name "username"
```

But with no use - I still get *Permission denied (publickey)*.
Again - *git clone* works fine.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frist, check the current URL used to fetch:

`git remote show origin`

Then, if the fetch url does not match, change it using the following command:

`git remote set-url origin ssh://username@ip:port/repo_name`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me. Origin URL had different user so I've changed the value in every repo /.git/config file to my username.

Answer (score 0):

The user.name on Git config doesn't matter in Git fetch/clone command it's used only in Git commits.

How did you execute the clone?

Have you used the following?

```
git clone ssh://username@ip:port/repo_name
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I used clone. See Gerardo Garcia answer as it fixed my problem :)

Comment: Ok. Have you executed "git remote show origin" like Gerardo suggested? It's important to know what is the root cause of your issue or you'll always have to execute the "git remote set-url" command after every clone you do.

Comment: I've checked /.git/config file in a meantime and wrong username brought my attention there. I've changed it to mine and git fetch started to work. Solution @garciadeblas proposed is leading to the same fix, because "git remote show origin" shows data from /.git/config. So the permanent fix is to change /.git/config file.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you have changed in the config file... but AFAIK the user.name in the config file only affects newly created commits (this parameters hasn't any effect in clone/fetch command). If you want to check, look at the "user.name" item on "git help config" documentation.

Comment: Right now I don't have access to the repository but the parameter I've changed had SSH link to the repo which looked like this: ssh://username@ip:port/repo_name where username was wrong.