# how to generate an ssh key for another user?

Tags: ssh, gerrit, ssh-keygen

I am trying to clone to a gerrit server using another user `username2` however it fails with `Permission denied (publickey)`. I tried to generate an ssh key following the advice of [Server Fault question "how do you create an ssh key for another user?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/323958/how-do-you-create-an-ssh-key-for-another-user)

The following steps didn't work. What am I missing?

- `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/username2`
- `cp ~/.ssh/username2.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Added the username2.pub to  tech-gerrit.sd.company.com
- ~/.ssh/config

  ```
    Host tech-gerrit.sd.company.com
    HostName tech-gerrit.sd.company.com
    Port 29418
    User username2
    IdentityFile /Users/username1/.ssh/username2
  ```
- Tried to clone using below command

  ```
  git clone ssh://username2@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com:29418
  ```
- Logged in as username2 into gerrit and added the username2.pub to

Answer (score 2):

```
IdentityFile /Users/username1/.ssh/username2.pub
```

This may not be your only problem, but you're probably specifying the wrong file here. The key file with the *.pub* extension contains the public portion of the key. The corresponding file without *.pub* contains the private portion of the key. The `IdentityFile` directive expects the name of the private key file, not the public key file. Try changing this directive to:

```
IdentityFile /Users/username1/.ssh/username2
                                            ^-- note no ".pub"
```

and see if things work better.

Comment: tried that ,it didnt work ,I get the error `username2@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: I said it may not be your only problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to list the exact commands you used so we could also look for typos and know which of the answers in question 323958 you followed.  Also, it would be helpful to know about the software and configuration used on company.com.

Some things to try:

- GitHub and GitLab are set up to use `git` as the username. Perhaps company.com also does this. Try replacing `username2` with `git` in your `git clone` command.
- Make sure you use an RSA key as specified on the Gerrit website - `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/username2`
- The `Host` line in *~/.ssh/config* should match the name used on the command line, so `Host tech-gerrit.sd.company.com` - otherwise git and ssh won't use your entry in *~/.ssh/config* at all.
- read the [Gerrit ssh documentation](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/user-upload.html#openssh-host-entry) again

Comment: Updated the commands I used in my question,replacing username2 with git didnt work,am trying to clone from a gerrit server

Comment: @Flair - thanks for the details. I assume the first command was actually `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/username2`

Comment: one question is when running `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/username2`,its creates an ssh key ,but when I open the sshkey is not from username2,it is from username1 which is the one am logged into the machine,is that expected?

Comment: An ssh key is just an ssh key. It doesn't belong to anyone. The `user@host` at the end of the public key is a comment; ssh does not use them. (However, the files are owned by a Linux user, just like all other files on a Linux filesystem.) Did any of my additional suggestions solve your issue?

Comment: tried that ,it didnt work ,I get the error `username2@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: @Flair - Maybe this answer will fix this for you:  [git fetch in repo dir 'Permission denied'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832120/git-fetch-in-repo-dir-permission-denied-but-working-with-direct-link-with-user#answer-42832384)

Comment: No,I dont think its the problem..somehow the ssh public key is not used rightly....I am trying to clone as username2,Logged in as username2 into gerrit and added the username2.pub ,is that the right think to do?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Git SCM is designed to use `git` as the user for SSH cloning. All users public keys in the SCM is propagated to that user. So it shouldn't matter which user you're trying to clone, as long as there's a private key matching the public key in SCM.

You can check if the key works by running `ssh git@tech-gerrit.sd.company.com:29418` and this should print a greeting that addresses the user with matching the private key

> I.E: For me with GitHub

```
➜  ~ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi praveenprem! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

> GitLab

```
➜  ~ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, @prav!
➜  ~
```

> BitBucket

```
➜  ~ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as pravd.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
➜  ~
```

As you can see, all main steam SCM systems use the same user for SSH, which is `git@`.

The only time you would need to use a username is when you're cloning a repo over HTTP/HTTPS. In which case you would normally use `username@`.

Hope this helps.

Also don't forget to load the private key to the agent.

Run `ssh-add -l` and if you get `The agent has no identities.` Try adding the key with `ssh-add`.